# In Python, how to check if a word is compatible with a specific format?

Tags: python, split, floating-point, format, substring

I have a list of words like my_list = {'(.,0)', '[6,.)', '(b)' , '(,2]'} in Python. Also, I have two predetermined string patterns like below:

- Pattrn_1: '/(/./,/a float number/)'
- Pattrn_2: '/[/float number/,/./)'

For instance, from my_list '(.,0)' matches Pattrn_1 and '[6,.)' matches with Pattrn_2.

Question: How can I check which word in the list is compatible with any of these predetermined patters??

Comment: You should look into regex

Comment: this should help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: use this `re.match(r'(\(\.,\d\))|(\[\d,\.\))',str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'\d*\.?\d*' may help you check float.

Try these two regular expressions:

```
pattern1: ^\(\.,\d*\.?\d*\)$
pattern2: ^\[\d*\.?\d*\,\.\)$
```

( I assume your example is correct and your description to pattern2 is actually closedbracket float comma dot parenthesis)

```
import re
r = '(.,0)'
if(re.match('^\(\.,\d*\.?\d*\)$',r) is not None):
    print('matches')
elif(re.match('^\[\d*\.?\d*\,\.\)$',r) is not None):
    print('matches')
```

Comment: Yes, thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. I know to how to check for number of characters in between parenthesis and comma but did not know to how to check if a substring is float.